# Why have CAUTION: request is not finished yet?

Tags: vue.js, request

I develop an application as front-end vuejs and back-end laravel.
When I call an API, I get this message: CAUTION: request is not finished yet!

See below my code and my problem:
my main component

```
<v-flex
            v-for="(danger) in get_alerts_current_danger"
            :key="danger.renter_id"
            wrap                
            xl4
            md6
            lg4
            xs12
            class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 float-left pl-0 ml-0"
            
        >
            <VueGlow class="col-12" color="red" elevation="12" :tile="true" :intense="true">
                <router-link
                    class="col-12"
                    :to="{
                        name: 'page_resident',
                        params: { id: danger.renter_id },
                    }"
                >
                    <Bar 
                        :renter_id="danger.renter_id"
                    >
                    </Bar>
                </router-link>

                <Chart
                    :key="'danger_chart_'+danger.renter_id"
                    :chart_type="get_current_type_alert(danger.vitalSign_id)"
                    :measures="get_measures_by_renter(danger.renter_id,get_current_type_alert(danger.vitalSign_id).toUpperCase())"
                    :height="200"
                    :ranges="get_ranges_by_renter(danger.renter_id)"
                    :time="set_xAxis()"
                ></Chart>   
            </VueGlow>
        </v-flex>
```

Component bar which call my twice API:

```
created(){
    console.log('bar.vue')
    const datas = {
        renter_id: this.renter_id,
        interval: 3600
    };

    
    this.measures_get_by_renter(datas);
    this.ranges_get_by_renter(this.renter_id);
},
```

and in this component, I have another component which call the last API

```
created(){
    console.log('bar_renter.vue')
    this.renters_get_by_id(this.renter_id);    
},
```

And when I go on the page with my brower:
[image]

And I must close my app because it is blocked in waiting my resquest in pending.

edit : see below the capture of network
[image]

with postman my request lasted 80 ms. So it is not my backend.

edit final : i resolved my problem, it was in my ackend, it missed a condition, it was strange...

Comment: Where do you get the caution message?

Comment: in my network tag browser

Comment: Can you show us, please? You've screenshotted that panel but not the error.

Comment: Can you please add what the backend error was that caused this?